# exponential distribution

Tags: self-study, exponential-distribution

The time it takes for a team to complete a certain task has an exponential distribution with mean equals to 80 hours.

Given that the task was not completed in 50 hours, what is the probability that the task will not be completed in more than 50 hours?

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be the task completion time. You're seeking an answer for $P(X>100|X>50)$, which can be written as $\frac{P(X>100 \ \cap \ X>50)}{P(X>50)}$ via Bayes Rule. The numerator is $P(X>100)$, so we need $\frac{P(X>100)}{P(X>50)}$, which can be easily found from exponential RV's CDF. The rest is on you, I believe.

Another way of solving this is using the **memoryless** property of exponential RVs, i.e. $P(X>a+b|X>a)=P(X>b)$. Either way, you're going to use CDF. By the way, since the mean is $80$, your $\lambda=1/80$.